# Blazor Get Parent ModelType from Child for reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

What I'm doing now:

ChildComponent

```
@typeparam TItem
@typeparam TValue

<input type="text" @bind=Value />

@code {
   [Parameter] public TValue Value { get; set; }
   [Parameter] public string PropertyName { get; set; }

   private void GetCustomAttributes() {
      PropertyInfo prop = typeof(TItem).GetProperty(PropertyName) as PropertyInfo;
      prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RegularExpressionAttribute), false)
      etc ...
   }
}
```

ParentComponent

```
<ChildComponent TItem="Student" TValue="string" @bind-Value="student.Firstname" PropertyName="@nameof(Student.Firstname)" />
<ChildComponent TItem="Student" TValue="string" @bind-Value="student.Lastname" PropertyName="@nameof(Student.Lastname)" />
<ChildComponent TItem="Student" TValue="int" @bind-Value="student.Age" PropertyName="@nameof(Student.Age)" />

@code {
   Student student = new Student();
}
```

Student

```
public class Student {

        [MaxLength(10)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[^a-zA-Z ]+")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[^a-zA-Z ]+")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

How could I make it simpler ? To get the PropertyName and the Type of the model in the ChildComponent by using only the binded value.

by providing only those information or less if possible:

```
<ChildComponent TItem="Student" @bind-Value=student.Firstname />
```